# Using the idiom "the sky is falling down" in a hopegiving sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms, sentence-usage

How should I use the idiom **the sky is falling down** when I'm going to say to someone in an understated way to that the situation is bad, but not too bad?

In other words, I need to make a similar sentence like **that's not the end of the world**, just using this structure.

Does the following sentence sound natural to you?

> **It's not as if** the sky is falling down.

Thank you.

Comment: That's a perfect sentence.  Also "It's not as if it's the end of the world."

Comment: I would suggest that @jonathanjo post that as an answer to be accepted so this question can be closed.

Comment: A simple search of >"the sky is falling down" idiom<, for example, would render this question moot. I'm voting to close the question for that reason. In addition, this question seems more like a solicitation of "writing advice" more than anything else, and is in appropriate for ELL for that reason.

Comment: @Jim Reynolds, it was **not at all** about asking advice for a writing style! It's absolutely comparing two completely close concepts in another language which sophisticates it's comprehending and sentence's structure. Meanwhile, as a non-native individual, I'm keen on discovering the way a native speaker would construct various sentences and that was why I opened the thread at hand here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion is a perfectly constructed way to say it

- **It's not as if the sky is falling down.**

Also **It's not as if it's the end of the world.**